# Using “allium” as an adjective

Tags: nouns, adjectives, suffixes, latin, derivational-morphology

I’d like to use the Latin word for garlic, *allium*, as an adjective, but can’t find any examples of this being done. Is there a rule for doing this with nouns ending in *‑um*? *Alliumnal* sounds good, but I suspect that’s just because it sounds like *autumnal*. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with *garlicky*?

Comment: Sorry, but downvoted due to no evidence of research.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Alliaceous** is used botanically for plants of the garlic/onion family; might it fit the bill?  (It’s much more standard than *allial*, I think, going both by dictionaries and google.)

Now I want to go out and order something big and garlicky at a restaurant, just so I can smack my lips and say “Mmmmm!  Alliaceo-licious!”.  Or, not quite, because it would just confuse people.  But I’m enjoying the idea…

Comment: The correct word always fits the bill.

Comment: Supercalifragilisticexpialliaceous, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

*Allium* is already used in English to mean "a bulbous plant of a genus that includes the onion and its relatives". You could use *allium* as modifier.

**<sub>[Reference: the *New Oxford American Dictionary*.]</sub>**

Answer (score 2):

*Alluvium* gives *alluvial*, *pericardium* gives *pericardial*, *mycelium* gives *mycelial*, so I would go with **allial**.

Comment: But you risk a "huh?" from your readers.

Comment: Colin makes a good point.  If it's not a scientific context, you might consider replacing with "reeking" or "offensive"

Comment: Well, the constraint is “I'd like to use the Latin for…”. Given that, the solution is clearly *allial*. Now, if you have a different writing constraint, clearly garlicky is a better choice.

Comment: I'm writing an informal essay on growing garlic for the first time. I'm attempting to both add humor and to avoid repetition of the word garlic. My sentence is, "Growing my own was the final _______ frontier." So, obviously, "reeking" won't work. "Allial" does have the huh?-factor, but might be worth it.

Comment: As long as you've introduced "allium" beforehand, people should understand what you mean when you write "allial".  It might just take them a little while, that's all.

Comment: Now that I think more on it, there's really no reason "final allium frontier" won't work. Thanks all, for helping me work through this.